# How to add custom widget to Launcher3 as default widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-source, android-appwidget

I tried to add a my custom widget to android Launcher3(nexus 5, lolipop) i edit the file default_workspace_4x4.xml and add this code

```
<appwidget
    launcher:packageName="com.my.widget"
    launcher:className="com.my.widget.ui.widgets.custom"
    launcher:container="-100"
    launcher:screen="0"
    launcher:x="0"
    launcher:y="0"
    launcher:spanX="4"
    launcher:spanY="1" />
```

Do yon know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: I explore it, and you can't add custom widget :(

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but I was in the same situation right now and just found the way.

I was setting the class name but what's actually required is the name of the receiver for the widget provider declared in your Manifest.